# pt-kill show database in log

Tags: percona

We've enabled pt-kill on a few servers of us, but without the killing, only to monitor slow queries for now.

The only problem is, the log doesn't contain the database, only the query. Is there a way to enable in the log on what database the query is executed?

```
# 2012-09-12T10:31:23 KILL 419539612 (Query 138 sec) SELECT blog.*, blog_text.*, user.*

FROM blog AS blog
INNER JOIN blog_text AS blog_text ON (blog.firstblogtextid = blog_text.blogtextid)
INNER JOIN blog_user AS blog_user ON (blog_user.bloguserid = blog.userid)
LEFT JOIN user AS user ON (user.userid = blog_text.userid)


WHERE 1=1
    AND blog.state = 'visible'
    AND blog.dateline <= 1347438544
    AND blog.pending = 0
    AND blog_user.options_guest & 1
    AND ~blog.options & 8



ORDER BY blog.dateline DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging the database for the query is not currently a feature of pt-kill (as of version 2.1.x).

This feature has been requested in the past:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-toolkit/+bug/1015804

But it has not been implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's being run by vBulletin, if that helps.  You can speed up the query dramatically by indexing some of the referenced fields in the "blog" and "blog_user" tables.